# using NSDate to find the DATE from string

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I am having problem finding date from string that is formatted using **NSDateFormatter**

Now, I am using this code:

```
NSDate *afterDate=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:balanceDateAfter.stringValue];
```

This code returning date with GeorgianCalendar format but I want it in PersianCalendar.

I think if I use this code :

```
NSDate *afterDate=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:balanceDateAfter.stringValue locale:];
```

It will return true date format but I don't know how can I use **locale** to set appropriate date formatter ( or my system locale ).

---

`balanceDateAfter` in above codes is an `NSTextfield` with NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate`s do not have a calendar.  An NSDate represents an absolute moment in time as defined by the difference between that moment and the first instant of 1st January 2001 in GMT.  Basically, it's a positive or negative number of seconds, nothing more.

If you have an appropriate formatter assigned to the text field, you should get its value using [-objectValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-BAJEBHAE), not -stringValue.  That way, you will be given the `NSDate` directly and you won't need to parse the string yourself.

Comment: Wow, thank you dude !boooom, My problem solved. Thank you so much +1    
  
 `NSDate *afterDate=[balanceDateAfter objectValue];`